# Strapi v4 Expose filtered content-types as new content-types

Tags: strapi

Suppose i am developing a to-do app backed up by strapi.
I have the content-type task(title, status).
On this resource, i can successfully get only the tasks created by its own creator as to override the default behaviour where everyone with find access sees everything thanks to the post on

[this link](https://dev.to/paratron/limit-access-of-strapi-users-to-their-own-entries-298l)

Next, i want to expose the endpoint /executedtasks, which is just a filter on the status property of the /tasks endpoint. This is a simplification of my real issue where i will have to apply about 10 filters and i don't want it to become unwieldy.

So my question is, is it possible to create a content-type (on the admin panel) or code by selecting an existing one and filter some of the properties?

im not well versed on extending strapi other than customizing existing controllers and i assume i would have to create a new on (controllers/executedtask.js) from scratch and im afraid of messing something up.